# How to check whether an IPython notebook is still running?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

When doing data mining with an IPython notebook, often the calculation takes a long time. You wait for the `In [*]:` star to output something.

After several hours, I finally notice that the kernel is unresponsive. How exactly do I know whether the kernel is running or not? Is there a command in the Terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can check using this command:

```
 jupyter notebook list
```

You will have a list like that:

```
(virtualenv) user@machine ~/Projetos/python $ jupyter notebook list

Currently running servers:
http://localhost:8888/?token=311320580ea96e5740459b3668656c9a3f89ff0629937a80 :: /home/user/Projetos/python/bigclima-project
```